# como puedo crear un campo integer de 1 en laravel *resuelto*

Tags: laravel

```
 $table->integer('tipo', 1);
```

se puede hacer esto en laravel? me tira error.
en la bd necesito un campo integer(1)

lo he intentado de la siguiente forma pero sin exito

```
  $table->addColumn('integer', 'tipo', ['length' => 1]);
```

me tira como resultado lo siguiente en la BD

```
    tipo : int(11)
```

lo resolví de esta manera en el controlador:

```
   'tipo' => "required|max:1"
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que requires hacer? No puedes especificar un tipo de dato para un número de un solo dígito. Lo más sencillo es que uses `TINYINT` y hacer validaciones en tu código para asegurarte que ningún número sea distinto al rango que buscas.

Comment: necesito que el valor que ingresen pueda ser un  1 o un 2 no mas que eso, pero lo resolví de esta manera en el controlador:  'tipo' =>  "required|max:1"

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste la solución Te recomiendo que redactes una respuesta y la aceptes, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Otra opción sería cerrar la pregunta.